# Nested shared_ptr destruction causes stack overflow

Tags: c++

This is a more of design problem (I know why this is happening, just want to see how people deal with it). Suppose I have a simple linked list `struct`:

```
struct List {
    int head;
    std::shared_ptr<List> tail;
};
```

The `shared_ptr` enables sharing of sublists between multiple lists. However, when the list gets very long, a stack overflow might happen in its destructor (caused by recursive releases of `shared_ptr`s). I've tried using an explicit stack, but that gets very tricky since a tail can be owned by multiple lists. How can I design my `List` to avoid this problem?

**UPDATE:** To clarify, I'm not reinventing the wheel (`std::forward_list`). The `List` above is only a simplified version of the real data structure. The real data structure is a directed acyclic graph, which if you think about it is just a lot of of linked lists with shared tails/heads. It's usually prohibitively expensive to copy the graph, so data sharing is necessary.

**UPDATE 2:** I'm thinking about explicitly traversing down the pointer chain and `std::move` as I go. Something like:

```
~List()
{
    auto p = std::move(tail);
    while (p->tail != nullptr && p->tail.use_count() == 1) {
        // Some other thread may start pointing to `p->tail`
        // and increases its use count before the next line
        p = std::move(p->tail);
    }
}
```

This seems to work in a single thread, but I'm worried about thread safety.

Comment: you're mixing concerns. it'll end in tears. use std::list.

Comment: @RichardHodges Please see my update.

Comment: What about using `std::weak_ptr<List>` instead of `std::shared_ptr<List>` inside of `List` itself, and then store the shared `List` objects in a separate `std::list<std::shared_ptr<List>>` elsewhere?

Comment: @RemyLebeau That would prevent us from releasing memory as long as they are not used, no?

Comment: If they are not being used, remove them from the `std::list` and they will be freed, automatically nulling out any `std::weak_ptr` that refers to them.

Comment: Instead of moving each link to a local pointer, add it to a `vector` of pointers which will all be released at the same time.

Comment: added new answer in the light of our conversation.

Answer (score 5):

If you're having problems with stack overflows on destruction for your linked datastructure, the easiest fix is just to implement deferred cleanup:

```
struct Graph {
    std::shared_ptr<Graph>  p1, p2, p3;   // some pointers in your datastructure
    static std::list<std::shared_ptr<Graph>>   deferred_cleanup;

    ~Graph() {
        deferred_cleanup.emplace_back(std::move(p1));
        deferred_cleanup.emplace_back(std::move(p2));
        deferred_cleanup.emplace_back(std::move(p3));
    }
    static void cleanup() {
        while (!deferred_cleanup.empty()) {
            std::list<std::shared_ptr<Graph>>  tmp;
            std::swap(tmp, deferred_cleanup);
            tmp.clear(); } }
};
```

and you just need to remember to call `Graph::cleanup();` periodically.

Comment: If `deferred_cleanup` grows too long, it seems `tmp.clear()` can still cause a stack overflow?

Comment: @ZizhengTai: This is relying on a decent implementation of `std::list::clear` in your implementation that loops rather than calling the list node destructor recusively, but that seems likely for any non-broken standard libaray.  Otherwise they'd be crashing with stack overflows every time a long list was deleted.

Comment: Ah, I see. And what is the swap for?

Comment: because the `Graph` destructor modifies the `deferred_cleanup` list, we don't want to clear it directly.  So we swap and clear the temp and loop if any destructor added something back on to the deferred_cleanup loop.

Comment: @ChrisDodd That should require the swap be atomic?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Oh, I think I got you wrong. So we `swap` in case the process of clearing (or destructing) of the list itself creates even more things to be deleted, it that correct?

Comment: Correct.  `swap` is not atomic, so if you need multiple threads, you'll need a `lock_guard(mutex)` to avoid a data race.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thank you. Is it possible to make the cleanup operation deterministic (not depending on outside invocation) such that every list is freed as soon as it's destructed?

Answer (score 4):

this should do it. With a little work it can easily be made thread-safe (a little locking/atomics in the deleter engine)

### synopsis:

The shared_ptr's to the nodes are created with a custom destructor which, rather than deleting the node, hands it off to a deleter engine.

The engine's implementation is a singleton. Upon being notified of a new node to be deleted, it adds the node to a delete queue. If there is no node being deleted, the nodes in the queue are deleted in turn (no recursion).

While this is happening, new nodes arriving in the engine are simply added to the back of the queue. The in-progress delete cycle will take care of them soon enough.

```
#include <memory>
#include <deque>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

struct node;

struct delete_engine
{
    void queue_for_delete(std::unique_ptr<node> p);
    
    struct impl;
    static impl& get_impl();
};

struct node
{
    node(int d) : data(d) {}
    ~node() {
        std::cout << "deleting node " << data << std::endl;
    }
    
    static std::shared_ptr<node> create(int d) {
        return { new node(d),
            [](node* p) {
                auto eng = delete_engine();
                eng.queue_for_delete(std::unique_ptr<node>(p));
            }};
    }
    
    int data;
    std::shared_ptr<node> child;
};

struct delete_engine::impl
{
    bool _deleting { false };
    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<node>> _delete_list;
    
    void queue_for_delete(std::unique_ptr<node> p)
    {
        _delete_list.push_front(std::move(p));
        if (!_deleting)
        {
            _deleting = true;
            while(!_delete_list.empty())
            {
                _delete_list.pop_back();
            }
            _deleting = false;
        }
    }
};

auto delete_engine::get_impl() -> impl&
{
    static impl _{};
    return _;
}

void delete_engine::queue_for_delete(std::unique_ptr<node> p)
{
    get_impl().queue_for_delete(std::move(p));
}

struct tree
{
    std::shared_ptr<node> root;
    
    auto add_child(int data)
    {
        if (root) {
            throw std::logic_error("already have a root");
        }
        auto n = node::create(data);
        root = n;
        return n;
        
    }
};


int main()
{
    tree t;
    auto pc = t.add_child(6);
    pc = pc->child = node::create(7);
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks really interesting! Can you give me some more advice on how to implement a thread-safe version that doesn't block the `node` destructor? Assume I have a decent concurrent queue at hand.

Comment: An atomic bool to act as the mutex to control who deletes. Use compare-exchange to set it

Comment: Is there a way to make a list self-contained? I.e., something like putting the delete engine in the last node…?

Comment: @ZizhengTai the delete engine is a lightweight singleton, but if you are thinking of holding one per tree that's fine, just give it a shared_ptr impl and create it in the base of the tree. you could even have one per thread (zero contention in the deleter then). The point of the value-type semantics of the deleter is that you can modify the implementation without changing the interface.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not worrying about the space the delete engine takes, but the possibility that it may become the bottleneck in certain applications (say, an HTTP server that constantly creates and destroys lots and lots of lists (one per request, perhaps)?).

Answer (score 2):

std::shared_ptr (and before that, boost::shared_ptr) is and was the de-facto standard for building dynamic systems involving massive DAGs.

In reality, DAGs don't get that deep (maybe 10 or 12 algorithms deep in your average FX pricing server?) so the recursive deletes are not a problem.

If you're thinking of building an enormous DAG with a depth of 10,000 then it might start to be a problem, but to be honest I think it will be the least of your worries.

re the analogy of a DAG being like a linked list... not really. Since it's acyclic all your pointers pointing "up" will need to be shared_ptr and all your back-pointers (e.g. binding message subscriptions to sink algorithms) will need to be weak_ptr's which you lock as you fire the message.

disclaimer: I've spent a lot of time designing and building information systems based on directed acyclic graphs of parameterised algorithm components, with a great deal of sharing of common components (i.e. same algorithm with same parameters).

Performance of the graph is never an issue. The bottlenecks are:

1. initially building the graph when the program starts - there's a *lot* of noise at that point, but it only happens once.
2. getting data into and out of the process (usually a message bus). This is invariably the bottleneck as it involves I/O.

Comment: You are right, general DAGs can't be expressed like that. Our case is a little special, it's basically a reversed tree.

Comment: I found this problem coming from Scala. With GC this isn't a problem, but I realized I can't just fire-and-go similarly in C++.

Comment: @ZizhengTai how deep is the graph going to be?

Comment: In practice most of the time it should work, but in theory it can grow over 10000 levels deep (which is around the number the stack blows).