# Delete engine for deeply nested linked structure

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11

The background is the question at [Nested shared_ptr destruction causes stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634394/nested-shared-ptr-destruction-causes-stack-overflow). To summarize, for a data structure that looks like:

```
// A node in a singly linked list.
struct Node {
    int head;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> tail;
};
```

If the list grows too long, a stack overflow might occur in the destructor of `Node` due to recursive destructions of the `shared_ptr`s. I'm implementing a thread-safe version of the delete engine proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36635668/3234803.

There are three simple classes involved: `SpinLock`, `ConcurrentQueue`, and `DeleteEngine`.

The `SpinLock` class implements the C++ Lockable interface with a `std::atomic_flag`:

```
class SpinLock {
public:
    void lock()
    { while (lock_.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire) {} }

    bool try_lock() // Not camel-case to be compatible with C++ Lockable interface
    { return !lock_.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire); }

    void unlock()
    { lock_.clear(std::memory_order_release); }

private:
    std::atomic_flag lock_ = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
};
```

The `ConcurrentQueue` class implements a multiple-producer-single-consumer queue that supports thread-safe `enqueue` and `tryDequeue`:

```
template<typename T>
class ConcurrentQueue {
public:
    void enqueue(T item)
    {
        std::lock_guard<SpinLock> lk(lock_);
        queue_.emplace_back(std::move(item));
    }

    bool tryDequeue(T &item)
    {
        std::lock_guard<SpinLock> lk(lock_);
        if (queue_.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
        item = std::move(queue_.front());
        queue_.pop_front();
        return true;
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> queue_;
    SpinLock lock_;
};
```

The `DeleteEngine` class implements the delete engine proposed in the answer aforementioned:

```
template<typename T>
class DeleteEngine {
public:
    ~DeleteEngine()
    {
        std::lock_guard<SpinLock> lk(deleting_);
        deleteAll();
    }

    void enqueue(T *p)
    {
        queue_.enqueue(p);
        if (deleting_.try_lock()) {
            std::lock_guard<SpinLock> lk(deleting_, std::adopt_lock);
            deleteAll();
        }
    }

private:
    void deleteAll()
    {
        T *p = nullptr;
        while (queue_.tryDequeue(p)) {
            delete p;
        }
    }

    ConcurrentQueue<T *> queue_;
    SpinLock deleting_;
};
```

Now in the deleter of a `shared_ptr<Node>`, we will hand the raw pointer to a `DeleteEngine<Node>` instead of directly `delete`ing it. A recursive `delete` can handle up to about 10000 nodes, while this method can handle an arbitrarily large number of nodes.

The above code is only a prototype, but I'm particularly concerned about the performance of this implementation: (1) Most of the time the `Node` class would be used in a single-threaded environment; (2) Occasionally it might be used in highly concurrent applications, e.g. a web server that constantly creates and destroys objects.

This implementation is significantly slower than a naive recursive destruction (micro-benchmark with 64 threads and 10000 nodes per thread shows about 10 times slowdown). What can I do to improve it?